# Using OpenCV 2.3.1 with Windows Form Application in visual studio 2010 express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, clr

I want to make a GUI that shows two rectangles, one for normal camera input and other for camera output after some image processing, using windows form application in visual studio 2010 express. can you help me with the basic steps of configuring windows form application with OpenCV. I am pretty much familiar with using OpenCV in win32 console applications.
 Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would recommend using `C++/CLI` for creating Windows Forms if you want to interop with OpenCV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest Qt instead of windows form application..? It will give you more freedom for future development and at the same time give you the power to go cross-platform. There is [a very nice video tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ONxIy8itRA) which you can use as a base. Plus, OpenCV and Qt work **very** nicely together.

However, if your bigger app needs windows forms, you could follow [this tutorial](http://ac-it.pl/display-an-iplimage-in-a-mcfc-form-application-using-opencv) which shows how to integrate OpenCV with windows forms.

HTH